# Why is this error in log into phpMyAdmin?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, localhost, port

I typed `http://localhost:81/phpmyadmin/`.Because of my apache port is 81.
then I get following error.How I fix this error.

[image: error]

Comment: Looks like you haven't configured the correct username and password in the PMA configuration.

Comment: @Barmar, sir can you say.how I edit those information.

Comment: I don't use PMA. Read the PMA documentation, it says where to enter the credentials.